# Bloquear acesso a páginas PHP com SESSION

Tags: php, mysqli, session

Estou praticando o PHP.

Estou montando um painel de administração com tela de login.

Tenho a minha pagina index.php que é o login (EMAIL E SENHA).

Após logar direciona a pagina administrativo.php

O detalhe é que se o usuário digitar www.seusite.com.br/administrativo.php, ele acessa direto a página.

Eu tenho uma pagina valida.php que cria nível de acesso a usuários

```
<?php
session_start();    
//Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
include_once("conecta.php");    
//O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
if((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['senha']);
    $senha = $senha;

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($con, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: administrativo.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: colaborador.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
            header("Location: cliente.php");
        }else{
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    }else{  
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
        }
    else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Funciona bem isso.

Tentei colocar isso logo após a busca das informações na tabela

```
if (! isset($_SESSION["usuarioSenha"],$_SESSION["senha"])) 
//aqui pega o valor do nome do campo da pagina de login  echo
"<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
```

//caso não esteja correto ela envia para a pagina index para fazer o login novamente }

Mas não rola

Essa é a minha página administrativo.php

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Administração</title>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascriptpersonalizado.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div class="conteudo">
<span style=" text-align: left; float: left; font-size: 20px; color: #000; line-height: 41px;">
Administração curriculos</span>
<div class="topo">

<?php

    echo "<span>Conectado como:</span> ". $_SESSION['usuarioNome']; 
?>

<br>
<a href="sair.php">Sair</a>
</div>
</div></div>

<div class="conteudo">
<form method="POST" id="form-pesquisa" action="">
            Buscar pelo nome: <input type="text" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Digite um nome">
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Zerar pesquisa">
        </form>

        <ul class="resultado">
<?php
include("consulta.php");
?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Outra eu tenho o include (consulta.php)

```
    <?php    include("conecta.php");
// executa a consulta $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY id"; $selec ="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE destino"; $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);   // conta o número de registros $total = mysqli_num_rows($res);
echo "<p>Resultados encontrados: " . $total . "</p>";   
// loop pelos registros while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
 echo "<p>" . $f['nome']. " | ". $f['email'] . " | ". $f['telefone']. " | "         . $f['destino']. " | ". "</p>"; }

    // fecha a conexão mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Que faz a consulta no banco e exibe uma lista dos cadastros.

Se eu digitar no navegador www.seusite.com.br/consulta.php
Acessa a página direto, gostaria que se ele digitar isso direto no navegador direcione ele para o index.php se não estiver logado.

Tenho outras páginas que somente podem ser acessadas com login.

alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fiz esse arquivo chamado segunrança.php, e fiz o include.

```
<?php
    function seguranca_adm(){
        if((empty($_SESSION['usuarioId'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioEmail'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId']))){       
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }else{
            if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] != "1"){
                $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Isso é uma resposta da sua pergunta?

Comment: A solução para a pergunta

Answer (score 1):

o uso de `<script>window.location='index.php'</script>` para redirecionamento é totalmente não recomendável já que simplesmente desativando o javascript do navegador é possível ter acesso sem problema algum. Ao invés disso modifique o header antes de envia-lo para o navegador através do método header do php:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Tente alterar o código da verificação de:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION["usuarioSenha"],$_SESSION["senha"]))
```

para:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION["usuarioSenha"]) || isset($_SESSION["senha"]))
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou, valeu a dica, somente adaptei um pouco.

Comment: Opa, que bom que deu certo. Até mais.

Answer (score 0):

Opa vou postar aqui o meu resultado.
Aqui é a pagina valida.php - que sai do form

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao/conexao.php");

 //Verifica se os campos possuem dados 
if((isset($_POST['txt_usuario'])) && (isset($_POST['txt_senha']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txt_usuario']); 
    //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txt_senha']);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    //Consulta a tabela de acordo com o email do usuário e senha
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha'";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);



    //Encontrando um usuário na tabela usuario com os mesmos dados digitado pelo usuario
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];

        //cria a variavél id pelo resultado no banco.
        $id = $resultado['id'];
        //faz update na coluna data_acesso e coloca o dia de hoje, para exibir o último acesso
        $sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET data_acesso=now() WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result_log = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


        //aqui faz o nivel de acesso conforme o usuário e direciona a página de acesso
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: administrativo.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: colaborador.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
            header("Location: cliente.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Erro - Entre em contato com marcelorossi007@gmail.com";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }

    //se ele não tem permissão retornar a tela de login
    else{
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Dai na página crio a página segurança

```
<?php
function seguranca_adm(){
    if((empty($_SESSION['usuarioId'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioEmail'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId']))){       
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] != "1"){
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
}

function seguranca_colaborador(){
    if((empty($_SESSION['usuarioId'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioEmail'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId']))){       
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] != "2"){
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
}

function seguranca_cliente(){
    if((empty($_SESSION['usuarioId'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioEmail'])) || (empty($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId']))){       
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] != "3"){
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Área restrita";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
        }
    }
?>
```

Então em nada página que quero que sejá validado o usuário

Eu insiro no topo de cada página

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("seguranca.php");
    seguranca_adm(); //para página com permissão adm
    seguranca_colaborador(); // para nível de permissão colaborador/moderador
    seguranca_cliente(); // para nível publico ou cliente
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Cordialmente,

Answer (score -1):

Se você quer bloquear/redirecionar o acesso a uma página como você mesmo explicou de digitar no navegador a página www.blabla.com/administrativo.php. Você tem que bloquear o método GET de acesso a ela, adicionando no início da página que quer bloquear o seguinte código:

```
<?PHP
$host = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($host == 'GET') {
    header("Location: block.php");
}
```

Pronto, caso o acesso venha digitando a URL no navegador o método é GET e você estará redirecionando para uma página de bloqueio, mas se o usuário for na página de autenticação, ele acessa o administrativo.php via método POST e a página vai abrir normalmente.

Comment: Simplesmente usando if($_GET) já bloqueia qualquer interação por meio do "get"

Comment: Verdade..... (:

Comment: Vaaleu!!! Problema resolvido. obrigado pelas dicas amigos